# Is it possible to use Clang-Tidy with QNX?

Tags: c++, qnx, clang-tidy

I have a QNX specific code and I want to use clang-tidy for static analysis. Is this possible?

I am struggling because clang-tidy is supported by the clang compiler, and QCC (QNX compiler) is based on GCC.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially yes. clang-tidy works with C++ source files and it mostly doesn't matter what compiler you use. As long as your program *would* compile with Clang, you can use clang-tidy.

However, although Clang is mostly compatible with GCC, the compatibility is not 100% proof and it may be confused if you use GCC / QCC specific features that are foreign to Clang. With standard, non-experimental C++ there should not be a problem.

Another consideration is that clang-tidy is typically used in conjunction with "compilation database", which invokes it with exact compiler options that you use to compile the program. Here again, Clang supports most GCC options either fully, or ignores them for compatibility, but some new, obscure or QCC specific options do cause an error.